# Hashtable library in Java

Tags: java, hashtable

Hey I'm currently doing a program which uses the already built in hashtables in java. I'm just wondering how do I get certain values that take up the same index in the hashtable if they're dealt with by singly linked lists.

As if the word "meat" and "mate" and "team"  take up index number 285, how would I get the word "team" instead of meat, or the other way around?

Thanks

-EDIT

Sorry I meant if I looked up the word say, 'meat', how would I get all the other words in that index as opposed to looking up the index like I said.
I just want to return all the values at the index in the hashmap

Comment: As pointed by Kayaman, Dont use hashtable. Also you are talking about getIndex. Hashtable/Map works based on hashcode so better go through it once to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Java 8, then HashMap uses a tree for collisions.  This means that the worst case time for put/get/remove is `O(log N)` instead of `O(N)` for a linked list as it was in previous versions.

You can also use ConcurrentHashMap for concurrent access.

> As if the word "meat" and "mate" and "team" take up index number 285, how would I get the word "team" instead of meat, or the other way around?

You ask for the key, not the index.  It will only get the value if the key matches. If you ask for a key which is not there, but would have a collision, `map.get(key)` will return `null`.

Comment: Asking for an index also does not even make sense in a HashMap. The iteration order is not guaranteed to be the same.

Comment: @Neijwiert the hash map uses an array internally, which is accessed by index and you can get all the entries for a single bucket using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use `Hashtable`, it's an outdated class (for over 15 years). Use `HashMap` instead.
2. The public API in either class doesn't provide the functionality you're looking for, so you don't have a nice and clean way to do what you want.
3. Your possibilities are either ugly reflection hacks, or creating your own implementation that does provide you with the methods to access the internal structure.

Comment: HashMap was a suitable replacement for Hashtable in 1998 (Java 1.2)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Would you believe that I knew that year, but still calculated the time wrong....

Comment: Java 5.0 was around ten years ago. :P

Answer (score 0):

As specified by Kayaman in the above answer,I would also suggest to use Hashmap over hashtable since it is advisable to use hashtable only when you need to perform thread safe operations.